# correct logical URI for fs.defaultFS and dfs.nameservices?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i followd apache documentation for setting up Hadoop HA Namenode

in core-site.xml i have the following

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://apache-hadoop-namenode:8020</value>
</property>
```

in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>apache-hadoop-namenode</value>
</property>
```

should value of both be the same? if so should I need to mention the port **8020** as shown above or not?

Answer (score 0):

`dfs.nameservices` can be a comma-separated list of NameServices. NameServices do not include protocols or ports.

If you have no NameServices, then `hdfs://apache-hadoop-namenode:8020` would refer to a DNS name, not a NameService

This page covers federation and configuration of nameservices. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs-rbf/HDFSRouterFederation.html